# How do I re-execute the render method when using react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a generic component `EcoPoema` defined in the render method to reutilize across several routes, when they switch, they change fine but `EcoPoema` doesn't get updated because it is not defined inside the route and it doesn't get re-created, it re-renders (`componentDidUpdate` is called) but it doesn't know about the updated props...

I understand what's happening, and I could fix this by copypasting the same code in every route, but that seems off, there must be a better solution, right?

```
updateState = (myKey, newState, callbackPromise) => {
    this.setState({
        [myKey] : newState,
    }, () => {
        if (callbackPromise !== undefined){
            callbackPromise();
        }
    })
}

render() {
    let ecoPoema =
        <EcoPoema
            updateState={(nkey, nValue, callbackPromise) => {
                this.updateState(nkey, nValue, callbackPromise)
            }}
            date={this.state[Constants.STATE_FECHA_NACIMIENTO]}
            mail={this.state[Constants.STATE_EMAIL]}
            nif={this.state[Constants.STATE_NIF_NIE]}
            phoneNumber={this.state[Constants.STATE_TELEFONO_CLIENTE]}
            codPostal={this.state[Constants.STATE_CODIGO_POSTAL]}
            capital={this.state[Constants.STATE_CAPITAL_ASEGURAR]}
        />
    return (
        <HashRouter basename={routes.URL_TARI_BASE}>
            <Switch key={HISTORY.location.pathname} pathname={HISTORY.location.pathname}>
                <Route path={routes.STEP_TARI_FECHA_NACIMIENTO}
                    component={props =>
                        {ecoPoema}
                        <ComponentA
                            updateState={(nkey, nValue, callbackPromise) => {
                                this.updateState(nkey, nValue, callbackPromise)
                            }}
                        />
                    }
                />

                <Route path={routes.STEP_TARI_EMAIL}
                    component={(props) =>
                        {ecoPoema}
                        <ComponentB 
                            updateState={(nkey, nValue, callbackPromise) => {
                                this.updateState(nkey, nValue, callbackPromise)
                            }}
                        />
                    }
                    />

                <Route path={routes.STEP_TARI_TELEFONO}
                    component={(props) =>
                        {ecoPoema}
                        <ComponentA />
                    }
                />
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Are `<ComponentA />` and `<ComponentB />` able to change the state in the parent?

Comment: @RafaelQuintanilha  
Yes! I updated the codeto reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can **wrap `EcoPoema` in a `withRouter` HOC**, which renders it wrapped in a pathless `Route`.

This will trigger a re-render of the component each time the URL path changes.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

...

let ecoPoema = withRouter(
    <EcoPoema
        ...
    />
)
```

---

More on that [in the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

Comment: If i just wrap `EcoPoema` in a `withRouter`, now it doesn't even render the first time. :(

Comment: And thanks for updating your question, I wasn't sure of exactly where I had to wrap `EcoPoema`.